# Converting UTC to Decimal time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, calendar, timezone

**Background**

I want to create a new date/time system based on an old French version with some modifications.

This involves converting UTC date/times to new quantities:

- 12 months => 10 months
- 52 weeks => 36.5 weeks
- 28/31 days per month => 36/37 days per month
- 24 hours => 20 hours
- 60 minutes => 100 minutes
- 60 seconds => 100 seconds

I've coded a clock in JavaScript as proof of concept, but unsure as to whether I have correctly calculated everything, additionally whether it's the best approach:

**Code**

1) getDecimalDate() calculates the day of the year, then works out which month it exists within a new calendar of 36 or 37 days per month. Then calculates the new date of the month.

```
function getDecimalDate(date) {
    var oldDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        startYear = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 0)),
        day = Math.floor((date - startYear) / oldDay),
        num = 0,
        month = 1;
    if (day > 36) { num += 36; month = 2; }
    if (day > 73) { num += 37; month = 3; }
    if (day > 109) { num += 36; month = 4; }
    if (day > 146) { num += 37; month = 5; }
    if (day > 182) { num += 36; month = 6; }
    if (day > 219) { num += 37; month = 7; }
    if (day > 255) { num += 36; month = 8; }
    if (day > 292) { num += 37; month = 9; }
    if (day > 328) { num += 36; month = 10; }
    return { day: day - num, month: month, year: date.getUTCFullYear(), num: num };
}
```

2) getDecimalTime() calculates the number of milliseconds since midnight, then changes it from old milliseconds per day to new totals, then calculates hours, mins etc

```
function getDecimalTime(date) {
    var oldDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
        newDay = 1000 * 100 * 100 * 20,
        startDay = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate())),
        delta = ((date - startDay) / oldDay) * newDay;

    var hours = Math.floor(delta / 10000000) % 20;
    delta -= hours * 10000000;
    var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 100000) % 100;
    delta -= minutes * 100000;
    var seconds = Math.floor(delta / 1000) % 100;
    delta -= seconds * 1000;
    var milliseconds = Math.floor(delta) % 1000;
    return { milliseconds: milliseconds, seconds: seconds, minutes: minutes, hours: hours };
}
```

You can see a working version here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/7mrwc3x3/9/

**Results**

Bear in mind i've made up day/month names using Latin (Nov = 9, die = day, dec = 10, mense = month)

- String - Saturday December 3 => Novdie Decmense 10
- Date - 03-12-2016 => 10-10-2016
- Time - 22:47:52 => 18:98:43

**Questions**

1. Is the math correct?
2. Are there any issues with timezones? i've
   tried converting all Date objects to UTC but JavaScript can be
   tricky
3. Can I improve the code? the month selection seems like it
   could be improved but I couldn't figure out a better way to count 36
   and 37 day months. if (num % 36.5 === 1) wouldn't work?

Thanks!

**Update - 7th December 2016 - new versions based on solution:**
https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/7mrwc3x3/10/

https://github.com/kmturley/decimal-time

Comment: `Are there any issues with timezones? i've tried converting all Date objects to UTC but JavaScript can be tricky`..  Well a timezone is nothing more complicated than an offset, so I personally would keep the UTC bit of these functions.

Comment: All Date objects **are** UTC. The time zone offset is from the host, the non–UTC methods use that offset to calculate "local" values. If you use all UTC methods then you will get UTC values and the time zone offset is not used.

Comment: good point, I have some unnecessary code converting UTC to UTC there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the math correct?

You didn't say which months have 35 days and which have 36 so we have to accept that the *if* statements are correct. You don't show how *date* is created so it may or may not be OK. And you don't say what happens for leap years, this system seems to only have 365 days per year.

The following:

> - 24 hours => 20 hours
> - 60 minutes => 100 minutes
> - 60 seconds => 100 seconds

doesn't seem correct. Do you actually mean:

- 1 day = 20 decimal hours
- 1 decimal hour = 100 decimal minutes
- 1 decimal minute = 100 decimal seconds
- 1 decimal second = 1000 decimal milliseconds

Your strategy of getting the time in ms and scaling to decimal ms seems fine, I'll just make the following comments.

In *getDecimalTime* it is simpler to calculate *startDay* by first copying *date* then setting its UTC hours to zero:

```
startDay = new Date(+date);
startDate.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Then scale:

```
var diffMilliseconds = date - startDate;
var decimalMilliseconds = diffMilliseconds / 8.64e7 * 2.0e8;
```

so 1 standard millisecond = 2.314814814814815 decimal milliseconds

In the date function, the expression:

```
new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 0)
```

will create a date for 31 December the previous year (i.e. date of 0), if you're after 1 January then it should be:

```
new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1);
```

So likely you're one day out. Otherwise, the code seems to be correct. For me, the get decimal time function would be simpler as:

```js
function getDecimalTime(date) {
  // Pad numbers < 10
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n;}
  // Copy date so don't modify original
  var dayStart = new Date(+date);
  var diffMs = date - dayStart.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  
  // Scale to decimal milliseconds
  var decMs = Math.round(diffMs / 8.64e7 * 2.0e8);
  
  // Get decimal hours, etc.
  var decHr  = decMs / 1.0e7 | 0;
  var decMin = decMs % 1.0e7 / 1.0e5 | 0;
  var decSec = decMs % 1.0e5 / 1.0e3 | 0;
  decMs      = decMs % 1.0e3;
  return z(decHr) + ':' + z(decMin) + ':' + z(decSec) + '.' + ('0' + z(decMs)).slice(-3);
}

// Helper to format the time part of date
// as UTC hh:mm:ss.sss
function formatUTCTime(date) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n;}
  return z(date.getUTCHours()) + ':' + 
         z(date.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + 
         z(date.getUTCSeconds()) + '.' + 
         ('00' + date.getUTCMilliseconds()).slice(-3);
}

// Test 00:00:00.003 => 00:00:00.007
// i.e. 3ms * 2.31decms => 6.93decms
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2016,0,1,0,0,0,3));
console.log(getDecimalTime(d));

// Test 12:00:00.000 => 10:00:00.000
// i.e. noon to decimal noon
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2016,0,1,12,0,0,0));
console.log(getDecimalTime(d));

// Test current time
d = new Date();
console.log(formatUTCTime(d));
console.log(getDecimalTime(d));
```

Comment: wow amazing, this is exactly what I needed. Going to test now and open-source it at: https://github.com/kmturley/decimal-time Thanks!

Comment: updated fiddle with solution: https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/7mrwc3x3/10/ also based on Date.prototype which makes it much easier!